# Postgres Partition - Performance issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table partitioned by week. There is an index on start_time
When I run this -

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(uniq_id) FROM call_fact WHERE CAST(start_time AS DATE) = '2018-01-23' AND source_key=2;
```

It scans every partitioned table rather than going to the correct child table.Shouldn't the query optimizer be smart enough to pick the right child table? Is there a way to force postgres to go to the correct child table?

```
EXPLAIN(analyze, buffers) SELECT COUNT(uniq_id) FROM call_fact WHERE CAST(start_time AS DATE) = '2018-01-23' AND source_key=2;
                                                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=649579.52..649579.53 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=845.998..845.998 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=34839 read=1312
   ->  Append  (cost=0.12..647969.68 rows=643937 width=26) (actual time=175.416..792.387 rows=457658 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=34839 read=1312
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w42  (cost=259.52..43804.31 rows=13604 width=26) (actual time=16.957..16.957 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w42_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..256.12 rows=13825 width=0) (actual time=16.954..16.954 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w43  (cost=258.00..43186.24 rows=13425 width=26) (actual time=14.656..14.656 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w43_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..254.64 rows=13628 width=0) (actual time=14.653..14.653 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w44  (cost=272.45..45811.42 rows=14264 width=26) (actual time=5.930..5.930 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w44_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..268.88 rows=14460 width=0) (actual time=5.921..5.921 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w45  (cost=258.80..43538.05 rows=13534 width=26) (actual time=10.631..10.631 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w45_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..255.41 rows=13731 width=0) (actual time=10.630..10.630 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w46  (cost=258.38..43396.98 rows=13479 width=26) (actual time=14.289..14.289 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w46_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..255.01 rows=13678 width=0) (actual time=14.281..14.281 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w47  (cost=203.86..34194.57 rows=10556 width=26) (actual time=13.386..13.386 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w47_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..201.22 rows=10772 width=0) (actual time=13.384..13.384 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w48  (cost=279.31..47044.41 rows=14662 width=26) (actual time=10.149..10.149 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w48_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..275.64 rows=14828 width=0) (actual time=10.143..10.143 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w49  (cost=270.62..45091.94 rows=14064 width=26) (actual time=8.687..8.687 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w49_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..267.10 rows=14223 width=0) (actual time=8.684..8.684 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w50  (cost=251.05..41960.30 rows=13073 width=26) (actual time=18.181..18.181 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w50_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..247.78 rows=13247 width=0) (actual time=18.175..18.175 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w51  (cost=238.23..39983.46 rows=12434 width=26) (actual time=10.728..10.728 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w51_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..235.12 rows=12625 width=0) (actual time=10.726..10.726 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2017w52  (cost=231.37..38822.25 rows=12069 width=26) (actual time=5.907..5.907 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2017w52_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..228.36 rows=12257 width=0) (actual time=5.905..5.905 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2018w01  (cost=272.97..46008.85 rows=14313 width=26) (actual time=13.909..13.909 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2018w01_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..269.39 rows=14528 width=0) (actual time=13.908..13.908 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2018w02  (cost=259.65..43842.27 rows=13642 width=26) (actual time=12.807..12.807 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2018w02_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..256.24 rows=13841 width=0) (actual time=12.806..12.806 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_fact_2018w03  (cost=245.87..41477.94 rows=12905 width=26) (actual time=10.540..10.540 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared read=3
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on call_fact_2018w03_cast_start_time_idx  (cost=0.00..242.64 rows=13095 width=0) (actual time=10.538..10.538 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
                     Buffers: shared read=3
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w04_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w04  (cost=0.43..49688.01 rows=457898 width=26) (actual time=8.644..562.016 rows=457658 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 5782
               Buffers: shared hit=34822 read=1270
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w05_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w05  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=3
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w06_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w06  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w07_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w07  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w08_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w08  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w09_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w09  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w10_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w10  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w11_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w11  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w12_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w12  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w13_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w13  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w14_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w14  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w15_source_key_idx on call_fact_2018w15  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (source_key = 2)
               Filter: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w16_source_key_idx on call_fact_2018w16  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (source_key = 2)
               Filter: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w17_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w17  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Index Scan using call_fact_2018w18_cast_start_time_idx on call_fact_2018w18  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((start_time)::date = '2018-01-23'::date)
               Filter: (source_key = 2)
               Buffers: shared hit=1
 Planning time: 68.906 ms
 Execution time: 846.648 ms
```

Comment: If there is an index on `start_time` then no, an index on the _expression_  `CAST(start_time AS DATE)` will not be used. If you want the optimizer to use an index for that you need to index the expression.

Comment: Postgres ver 9.5.5. I'll index the expression and test.

Comment: I created an index on CAST(start_time as DATE), but I still see it doing an index scan on every one of the child tables.

Comment: set `constraint_exclusion` to `on` or `partition`

Comment: I set constraint_exclusion = partition, but still does not help

Comment: My thought is that the cast on the start time is throwing off the query optimizer, when I do this WHERE start_time = DATE '2018-01-23', its interpreted correctly and hits only the child table in question. Any thoughts @VaoTsun

Comment: sorry - weekend started - I'll give it some time

Comment: Can you show us the execution plan generated using **`explain (analzye, buffers)`** instead of a plain `explain`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name posted in the original question above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is the type of `start_time`? I assume it is `timestamp`, not a `date`.

The expression `CAST(start_time AS DATE)` prevents optimiser from using an index on `start_time`. Usually any kind of expression over the column prevents optimiser from using an index.

The common way to write this type of query is to compare original column value without wrapping it into expression with a closed-open interval.

```
SELECT COUNT(uniq_id) 
FROM call_fact 
WHERE 
    source_key=2
    AND start_time >= '2018-01-23'
    AND start_time <  '2018-01-24'
;
```

Postgres should be smart enough to implicitly convert the constant expression `2018-01-23` of the `date` type into the `timestamp` type. (rather than converting the values of the `start_time` column into the `date` type. What type is converted into what type is governed by rules for the implicit type conversions. In SQL Server it is called the "type precedence", but I could not find a relevant page in the Postgres docs.

To make it explicit and not relying on type precedence and implicit rules I would explicitly write the date/time literal in such a way that it is of `timestamp` type that matches the type of the column.

```
SELECT COUNT(uniq_id) 
FROM call_fact 
WHERE 
    source_key=2
    AND start_time >= '2018-01-23 00:00:00'
    AND start_time <  '2018-01-24 00:00:00'
;
```

When the query is written in this way nothing should stop optimiser from using the index on `start_time`.

Comment: The start_time type is timestamp without time zone. The query is being generated with the cast expression by a reporting tool, and there is no way to force it to use a range. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @sharadov, well, with these kind of limitations you don't have many options. Leaving obvious option to use a different tool aside, you can make sure that the type of the column is `date`, rather than `timestamp`. In this case the cast should not be needed. If you actually store time component and you need the time component, you can add an extra field that would have a `date` type and use that field in the reporting tool. In SQL Server it would be called a "persisted computed column", so that it is populated automatically by the server and it is actually part of the index data on disk.

Answer (score 0):

See Vladimir's answer for great explanation of why this happens.

You can also use prepared query to bind a typed valued parameter to the query - which can then be used in the filter:

```
PREPARE query(timestamp) as 
    select max(b)
    from  customer
    where b > $1 - interval '1 months';     
   EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE query(current_date);
   -- You should deallocate your statement when you are done using it.
   DEALLOCATE query;
```

Read more about PREPARE https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html

Comment: Prepared statements cache query plans. If the generic plan is chosen after the sixth execution, no partition pruning can take place. Hopefully that shouldn't happen though.